# FFMpegCore C# custom args

Tags: c#, .net-core, ffmpeg

I am evaluating using FFMpegCore C# to do some video manipulations.  I am not seeing a way of passing in a custom argument string.  I fear the answer is staring right at me but I definitely read all documentation and cannot find a way to do it.

Below my signature is the string I would like to pass in, though it should not matter.  Anyone know how to pass a custom string arguments to FFMpegCore C#?

Thanks, Dan

```
public static string GetFlipBookArgs(string convertedVideoFilePath, int frameCountCalc, string flipbookFilePath)
{
    return $"-y -i \"{convertedVideoFilePath}\" -vf \"select = not(mod(n\\, {frameCountCalc})),scale = 128:128,tile = 4x4\" -frames:v 1 -q:v 10 \"{flipbookFilePath}\"";
}
```

Comment: were you able to figure out? I also find it too complex to build up your commands so instead would like a quick way of adding my raw arg list which I tested out before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FFmpegArgs.Executes](https://github.com/tqk2811/FFmpegArgs)

```
string your_arguments = "-y -i ......";
var render = FFmpegRender.FromArguments(
  your_arguments,
  new FFmpegRenderConfig()
    .WithFFmpegBinaryPath("path to ffmpeg")//default from PATH or current dir
    //.WithWorkingDirectory("your working dir or not")//default current dir
  );
//render.OnEncodingProgress += your update action
//var result = render.Execute(); 
var result = await render.ExecuteAsync();
```